# MSWord File download issue using HttpServlet

Tags: java, servlets, download

i have implemented a `servlet` to download doc files available under my application classpath.

what happening is; file is downloading but `ms-word` is unable to open it property.
see the screenshot of `ms-word`:

[image: msword screenshot]

`Servlet` implementation is as follows:

```
public class DownloadFileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fileName = "test.doc";
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(File.separator + fileName);
        ServletOutputStream sos = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {
            response.setContentType("application/msword");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; fileName=\"" + fileName + "\"" );

            fis = new FileInputStream(new File(resource.getURI().getPath()));
            byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);

            sos = response.getOutputStream();
            sos.write(bytes);
            sos.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        if( fis != null) {
            fis.close();
        }
        if( sos != null) {
            sos.close();
        }
        }
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

i have tried almost all suggested Content Types for `ms-word` files. but still it is not working.

```
application/msword
application/ms-word
application/vnd.ms-word
```

Kindly suggest I'm making a mistake or is there any other way to achieve.

Note: i have tried almost all approaches available on SO.

Comment: How did you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading, converting to byte[] simply write directly to the `OutputStream`. You shouldn't close the `OutputStream` as that is being handled by the container for you.

I would rewrite your servlet method to more or less the following (also why is it a servlet and not a `(@)Controller`?

```
protected void doGet(
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fileName = "test.doc";
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource(File.separator + fileName);

        InputStream input = resource.getInputStream();
        try {
            response.setContentType("application/msword");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; fileName=\"" + fileName + "\"" );
            org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(input, response.getOutputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOEXception ie) {}
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i do not know what a ClassPathResource class does. hence modified the code a bit.

ClassLoader clsLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

InputStream is = clsLoader.getResourceAsStream("test.doc");

and in the try block use:

byte[] bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(is);

this should work fine. i placed the doc in the classpath. modify it to suit your needs.

Regarding the mime mapping, open your server properties and you will find a list of mime mapping. Eg. in eclipse for tomcat, just double click on the server and you should be able to find the mime mapping list there. application/msword worked fine

Comment: Kindly reffer the following link regarding ClasspathResource: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html

Comment: I do not get whats wrong in the code. just added the spring core jar and your code works fine for me, the only change that i made is change temlateFileName to "test.docx" since i do not see its declaration. Do you see any errors in conosle ?

Comment: i have modified the question and corrected the variable name error for  temlateFileName

Comment: do you see any errors in conosle? and where have you placed the file? . Here it should be in the src directory